# R syntax for looping through a list of data frames to change class of a column to as.chron

Tags: r, list, loops, datetime

First, I show where I have succeeded, then I show where I am stuck at the bottom.

I received a datafile with observations collected over a number of years at different sites located in different time zones. I want to keep the times in the site local standard time (none of the sites switch to daylight savings time for their data collection). I have the following BIG df that has a total of 50 million rows and 150 unique site id’s:

```
siteid    year     month day   hourend   obs
30113     2012     1     1     01:00     6.3     
30113     2012     1     1     02:00     5.7     
30113     2012     1     1     03:00     5.2     
30113     2012     1     1     04:00     7.8
```

I combine year, month, day, hourend to get a datetime, like this:

```
df$datetime <- as.character(paste(df$year, df$month, df$day, sep="-"))
df$datetime <- as.character(paste(df$datetime, df$hourend))

siteid    year    month day    hourend   obs    datetime
30113     2012     1     1     01:00     6.3    2012-01-01 01:00        
30113     2012     1     1     02:00     5.7    2012-01-01 02:00        
30113     2012     1     1     03:00     5.2    2012-01-01 03:00        
30113     2012     1     1     04:00     7.8    2012-01-01 04:00
```

Then, I change datetime from character to chron:

```
df$datetime <- as.chron(df$datetime)   # using chron so it stays in the siteid local time & doesn't change to my machine system time which is what happens with POXITct and POXITlt.
```

This works fine with a smaller test df, but I get an approaching stack limit error when I try it on the BIG df that has 50 million rows. 
￼
I want to try and solve that problem by doing the same thing in a list of df’s:

I split my BIG df into a list (mylist) of df's by siteid, like this:

```
mylist <- split(df, df$siteid)
```

And, I can put it back together again, like this:

```
backtogetheragain <- do.call("rbind", mylist)
```

I realize that the name of each df in the list is mylist$siteid, and that I need to type quotes around the df name like this (mylist$’siteid'; e.g., mylist$'30113’) when I call it because the names of the df's are numeric (i.e. the siteid).

**Here's where I'm stuck**:

I want to use lapply to loop through the list of df's in mylist with as.chron(df$datetime) like I did before in the BIG df. Can someone help me get the syntax right? This isn’t working:

```
  lapply(seq_along(mylist),
         function(i)
           {as.chron(i$datetime)})
```

Comment: It's hard to know where to begin, since there are so many things wrong with what you are saying and attempting (and you have not yet figured out how to use SO markdown system. Why not post a few simple examples of structures like objects you are working with, and _do_ use `dput` to post an unambiguous R object. The print representations are often a confusing mechanism for dates, times and factors.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming and to R, and this is my first post on stack overflow. As far as I can tell, everything works until I get down to lapply. I would really appreciate it if you could list all the other things I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The longer you wait in responding to useful formative suggestions, the less likely it is that people will take you seriously. I'm going to bed. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
library(chron)
sampData <- data.frame(siteId=sample(1:10, 1000, replace=TRUE), reportDate = paste( sample(2000:2015, 1000, replace=TRUE),
  sample(1:12, 1000, replace=TRUE), sample(1:28, 1000, replace=TRUE), sep="-"), 
  hourend=sample(c("01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00"), 1000, replace=TRUE))  
sampData$dateTime <- as.character(paste(sampData$reportDate, sampData$hourend))
# split the data
dfList <- split(sampData, sampData$siteId)
# Apply the conversion function and return the data.frame
dfListNew <- lapply(dfList, function(x) { 
  x[["dateTime"]] <- as.chron(x[["dateTime"]])
  x
  } )
```

Hope it helps. The code is very clear to me. If you have any doubts, please comment.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! For some reason, I was able to run the code that had previously crashed on the BIG df and get a run time. Then I split the df's into a list and ran your  solution. It resulted in a 25% reduction in runtime. This is what I was hoping for. Now, the question is, why is it faster to do the same thing on the list than on the BIG df?

Comment: I dont know the exact reason, but I think that it is because of memory allocation, that R has to do , when the column type is changed. When the data is big, it is more difficult for R to find the contiguous memory space required for column type conversion. But in case of smaller data.frames, this is much easier for R.